# Laravel show blank page in local ubuntu 20

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 20, laravel project run using **php artisan serve** but when I access the site using this URL **laravel-local.com** it shows blank page

**Could not get any error**

**sites-available**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin admin@MyWebsite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel-local.com/public
  ServerName laravel-local.com

  <Directory /var/www/html/laravel-local.com/public>
     Options +FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**What I tried**

1. Give project 777 access
2. Change the ownership
3. Delete the folder inside the storage/framework
4. Change the storage  folder permission
5. composer dump-autoload, php artisan cache and config clear
6. Delete .htaccess file in public folder

I tried all the above steps still got a blank page

**.htaccess file in root folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess in the public folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is that the only `.htaccess` file you have? And where exactly is it? What is the HTTP response you are getting?

Comment: There are 2 .htaccess files one is in the root folder and the other is inside the public folder

Comment: According to your vHost config, the `/public` folder IS the "root folder". This is what I've addressed in my answer. You don't need two `.htaccess` files with your particular config.

Comment: @MrWhite added the .htacess file code which is in the public folder

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is that blank page thrown by Laravel itself? What's the status code?

Comment: Blank page thrown by laravel

Comment: "Blank page thrown by laravel" - so Laravel handles the request? What's the expected output then? Are you sure this is in any way related to Apache, if the request is properly handed to the PHP process?

Comment: Request properly handle, Laravel should show the default page, but it's showing blank page

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that? How did you configure that "default page"? Also, please add all details to your question by editing it

Comment: I wrote all the steps in the question to solve this problem, but still got blank page

Comment: How do you know that it is "Laravel" that is responding with the blank page and not Apache? And what is the HTTP response code? Does the server's error log report anything?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to find status code

Comment: You get the status code from the Network tab in the browser dev tools. (This is really the first place you should look to help diagnose such a problem.)

Comment: laravel-local.com/index.php/login shows (blank page),  but when I access the page using laravel-local.com/login its shows 404 (The requested URL was not found on this server)

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Have you tried enabling the debug mode to get more information? What else did you try to resolve the problem? Like: add some `var_dump` here and there? Check the server's log files?

Comment: "when I access the page using laravel-local.com/login its shows 404" - Is mod_rewrite installed? Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper in the `.htaccess` file - do you get a 500 error? (When you call the URL `/index.php/login` you are not actually using `.htaccess`)

Comment: var_dump and dd not work always show the blank page, mod_rewrite installed
and also removed <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> wrapper still blank page

Comment: Ok, we _need_ to see the HTTP response headers and HTTP status code as mentioned earlier (check the browser devtools).

Comment: status 200 after doing all the above things that you mentioned

Comment: HTTP response headers? Server's error log? (ie. What you have defined in the vHost config: `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`)

Comment: https://ibb.co/qMPRDzC error log image

Comment: "var_dump and dd not work always show the blank page" - then I would assume it is not Laravel sending the black page, or you haven't added the dumps at the correct place. Have you checked whether the routing between the accessed URL and the entry point of your application works properly? What makes you think that Laravel is sending the blank page, while all dumping attempts do not work?

Comment: Routing does not work properly whatever page I access its show the blank page, I don't whether it's .htaccess or an apache issue, Also dumping not working

Comment: Then why not check whether this is a problem of the Apache configuration, or of Laravel? Also, please add all details to your question by editing

Answer (score 0):

> **sites-available**

**UPDATE:** Your vHost config should be defined in "sites-enabled" for the config to actually be applied. Create a symlink from "sites-enabled" to the actual config file in "sites-available". And restart Apache.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
> RewriteEngine  On
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
>
> </IfModule>
> ```

You don't need an `.htaccess` file like this (which would need to go in the directory *above* the `/public` directory) because you have already configured the `/public` directory as the `DocumentRoot` in the server config.

If you had also deleted the `.htaccess` file inside the `/public` subdirectory then this would have resulted in a rewrite-loop (500 error).

You just need the standard Laravel front-controller (`.htaccess` file) inside the document root, ie. in the `/public` subdirectory.

However, you should define the `DirectoryIndex` (if not already set somewhere in the server config), either in your vHost (`<Directory>` container) or at the top of your main Laravel `.htaccess` file (inside the `/public` folder). If this is not defined then requests to the Laravel directory itself (the homepage) will not be routed through Laravel and will likely result in a 403 Forbidden response (or worse, a directory listing if `Indexes` have been enabled) from Apache.

For example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: you mean delete the .htaccess file which is in the root directory?

Comment: Yes, except what you appear to be calling the "root directory" is in fact the directory _above_ the (document) root directory. You only need the `.htaccess` file inside the `/public` directory (which is now the "root directory" as defined by your server config). You also need to define the `DirectoryIndex` somewhere. I've updated my answer. If this is not defined then you'll get a 403 when accessing the root directory.

Comment: Add this line in public/.htaccess at the top still, blank page is showing

Comment: laravel-local.com/index.php/login shows (blank page),  but when I access the page using laravel-local.com/login its shows 404 (The requested URL was not found on this server)

Comment: That behaviour is consistent with `.htaccess` (ie. mod_rewrite) not doing anything - is mod_rewrite installed on your server? You should remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` ... `</IfModule>` wrapper - do you get an error?

Comment: Not getting any error removing the wraper

Comment: @MukkaramWaheed The config should be defined in "sites-enabled", not "sites-available" - I've updated my answer.